# For programming an android app: How do I make it display a one time setup screen

Tags: java, android, installation, screen

While searching this question I have seen this. [One time Android setup screen?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3025284/one-time-android-setup-screen)

It asks my question, but I can never get it to work. What I want to happen is when I first startup the app, it gives me the setup screen. Then when I press save, I want it to quit the app. When I click the app again, I want it to preform a task, rather than show up with a screen. So thats really 2 questions, how to make it show a setup screen one time, and then how to make it do an action(by clicking on the app) without a screen showing up at all.

Right now, I use SharedPreferences editor to input my settings.

Answer (score 1):

Pretty simple, in the onCreate of your activity:

```
   savedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    if(savedPreferences.getBoolean(PREF_SHOW_ABOUT_ON_APP_START, true)){        
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, SetupActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    savedPreferences.edit().putBoolean(PREF_SHOW_ABOUT_ON_APP_START, false).commit(); // YOu could do this line within the SetupActivity to ensure they have actually done what you wanted
                    finish();
    } else {
                 // Go somewere else
            }
```

You don't have to activity switch, but you get the picture

Comment: thanks!!!! This really helped

One more question, is it possible to run an action from an app without showing a layout? like in the else have a call someone function without displaying a screen, so I just hit the app and it calls someone

Comment: You could do your work (i.e. start a thread or service/remoteservice) then call finish() on the activity, that way it'll go away.

Comment: and then when they click on the app again I can remotely trigger the service? :)

Answer (score 0):

For the first time only set up screen, you simply have to use SharedPreferences. Check if a value, alreadyLaunched exists in the shared preferences. If not, show the set up screen. If yes show your app.

For the second part of your question, it would be considered very bad practice to have an icon app that does nothing at all when you click it. How would the user know that it worked or did what it was supposed to do ?

For the "I want a task to execute but I don't want the user to see it happening", I believe you should look at services. When your user closes the app clicking the save button on the set up screen, start a service ( http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html )

When the user clicks again on your app, simply show a message and make the app call the service via an intent.

Answer (score -2):

Probably you are forgetting to call

`myEditor.commit()`

after you are done with setting your preferences.

Comment: It have the commit at the end of the putBoolean(...)